# Is javax.swing.timer's interval constant?

Tags: java, swing, timer

In `javax.swing.Timer`, we are allowed to set the *time interval* as such:

```
int delay = 1000;    //update every 1000 millisecond
Timer t = new Timer(delay, listener);
```

With the above, I will expect the time delay between each interval to be `1000` millisecond. However I when I use it in a Swing application, the delay for each interval is `1014 to 1015`.

When I set the delay to `1`. The tested delay is `15 to 16` milliseconds per interval.

---

I have 2 question with regards to the above Timer behaviour:

**Q1**: What is causing the additional `14 to 15` milliseconds being added to my interval? Is it the "overhead" needed to run the Swing application?

**Q2**: Will the time delay be guaranteed as what we have stated in the Timer constructor or `timer.setDelay()`? I ask this because I know the delay in `Thread.sleep(delay)` is not guaranteed, and it varies with a range. So, what about `javax.swing.Timer`?

Comment: *"Is javax.swing.timer's interval constant?"*  Nope.  It is not guaranteed down to the last millisecond & will drift over time.  A good strategy for things that should be more constant is to make the timer fire significantly faster than the required delay, and perform the action (repainting or whatever) as a new time period specified by the app. ticks ofer (e.g. set the timer for 10 msec, but do the action after each whole second has passed).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for your reply. In that case it is unlikely we can use javax.swing.Timer to achieve a frame rate above 65 fps right? Because even setting the delay to minimum (1 ms), the delay will end up becoming 15-16ms (approximately 60 fps). Hope to hear from you. :)

Comment: Take a look at Swing Timing Framework: https://java.net/projects/timingframework/pages/Home

Comment: @keuleJ Thanks, I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer uses a sleep operation which is implemented by the operating system.  When you run a 32-bit application on Windows, it uses the Win XP emulator which work the same way as it would on Window XP.

If you use the 64-bit JVM which will take advantages of improvements in the OS clock, it should run with 1 milli-second resolution.

Note: `ExecutorService` added in Java 5.0 uses `System.nanoTime()` and `LockSupport.parkNanos(n)` which shouldn't have this problem at it uses high resolution clock.

Comment: I just checked, I am indeed using 32-bit JVM. So can I assume that if I switch to a 64-bit JVM, `Javax.Swing.Timer`, I will be able to run the timer with a minimum of `1ms` instead of `16ms`?

Comment: @user3437460 that is my expectation, though it might be time to use an ScheduledExecutorService instead as it is much newer (only about ten years old)

Comment: @user3437460 javax.swing.Timer was added in Java 1.2 (1998) though it is designed to work with Swing, for anything else I wouldn't use it.