# Can a Thread sleep for less than half milli seconds in Java/ Other language?

Tags: java, c, multithreading, operating-system

*[Edit]: After getting answer I understood its not specific to Java, its related to OS scheduler as well, so adding other tags*

Is it possible in Java to make a thread sleep for a nano seconds.

Of course after looking the Thread api where we can pass nano seconds as well in sleep method, the answer could be yes.

But I doubt after looking the implementation/ source of sleep method in [Thread class](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/5672a2be515a/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java), which is:

```
public static void sleep(long millis, int nanos)
throws InterruptedException {
    if (millis < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }

    if (nanos < 0 || nanos > 999999) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "nanosecond timeout value out of range");
    }

    if (nanos >= 500000 || (nanos != 0 && millis == 0)) {
        millis++;
    }

    sleep(millis);
}
```

Now according to the logic it is increasing milli seconds by `1` if the passed nano seconds is more than *half milli seconds*. But this sounds illogical to me, lets say I have written a code where one of my thread is waiting for say some `40000 nano seconds` (in practical scenario it might not be the case) which is less than half milli seconds that means my thread will not wait at all.

Can someone please comment on the same and **why this design was decided to wait for milli seconds rather than nano seconds**?

Also what would guarantee that the thread wakes up accurately?

Comment: What would guarantee that the thread wakes up accurately?

Comment: @biziclop exactly. I will edit my question to add this point

Comment: @dr_debug its not duplicate, I am asking why this design was chosen rather than allowing thread to sleep for nano seconds

Comment: It is answered in that question too: because no major OS has a scheduler that runs at less than 1ms intervals. And since thread scheduling is done by the OS, Java is bound by what the OS can do.

Comment: No. And most operating systems have a system timer that is +/- 15 ms (which is rather more than nanoseconds).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch so you mean to say a thread will sleep at least for +/- 15 ms even if I have provided 1 ms in `sleep` method?

Comment: @Vishrant Yes. If you look at the API doc for `Thread.sleep()`, it explicitly says: `Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers.`

Comment: It's been my experience that a sleep of less than 5 milliseconds causes timing problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [LockSupport's parkNanos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#parkNanos-long-)

```
LockSupport.parkNanos(400_000);
```

however this is not the same as sleep (it is not interruptable) and all it does is pass the request to the OS. On Windows 8 for example, even `parkNanos(1)` might sleep for 1 milli-second.

As biziclop pointed out, there Javadoc mentions

> The call spuriously (that is, for no reason) returns.

This happens rarely in my experience, but it does happen.

---

However, you are right that Thread.sleep() will always sleep for at least 1 ms.  On Win XP it might sleep for 16 ms (1/60th of a second)

> Also what would guarantee that the thread wakes up accurately?

Using a real time operating system.

What I do, is don't go to sleep but rather busy wait.  This way I can stop for a give amount of time with more accuracy.  If you run your thread on an isolated CPU (In Linux) you can reduce the variation to about 10 micro-seconds

An example of busy waiting

```
long end = System.nanoTime() + delay;
while (System.nanoTime() < end) { /* busy waiting */ }
```

or if you want to be slightly more friendly

```
while (System.nanoTime() < end) 
     Thread.yield();
```

Comment: @jtahlborn I am not sure that you mean. It is a built in class called `LockSupport` with a method `parkNanos`  I have added a Javadoc.

Comment: I particularly like the fact that they admit that `parkNanos()` may return before time for no apparent reason.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey `On Win XP it might sleep for 16 ms (1/60th of a second)` Why is it so, is it based on how the Operating system works? And is there anyway we can reduce it below 16ms? I posted a similar question months ago, no one was able to answer it..

Comment: how can you be sure by busy wait your thread will wait for exact given time? can you please elaborate how you will implement busy wait?

Comment: @user3437460 Win XP uses a time slice of 1/60th of a second. A complication is that it can return in less time than this however the resolution of `System.currentTimeMillis()` is 1/60th of a second making it hard to be sure how long it took. Hint: you can use `System.nanoTime()` Hint 2: don't use Win XP. ;)

Comment: @Vishrant you can implement a busy wait by spinning until the desired amount of time has elapsed. i.e. keep polling System.nanoTime().

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am using win7 and when I use `Javax.Swing.Timer`, the minimum is around 16ms as well (I was disappointed that it cannot go below 16ms for unknown reason and I am forced to use `Thread.sleep()`). So I guess that is the same issue as what you mentioned in WinXp? Thanks a lot for your replies.

Comment: @user3437460 if you are using the Win XP emulator, it will behave like Win XP. i.e. 32-bit programs use the Win XP emulator. Try using the 64-bit JVM.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't agree with using yield() as other thread might get the resource and this thread will have to wait until it finishes, please correct me if wrong. The first approach is fine.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Will you be able to answer this question of mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888397/is-javax-swing-timers-interval-constant I will be more than glad to accept your answer if you could. :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey yield method documentation /*A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield its current use of a processor.*/ being more friendly could by hazardous for health.. ;)

Comment: @Vishrant even if you don't yield, another thread could just in. and even if there is no other thread running, the OS can, and will jump in from time to time.  Using `yield` does make delays more likely but you only have so many cores to burn and you can't have too many thread busy waiting.